# Saving user credentials on device for android

Tags: android, security, passwords

What is the best and safest way to save user credentials on device for an android app.
I was thinking of encrypting data and saving it in preferences.

Is there a way similar to iOS keychain to save passwords?

Comment: You should rather store the `Access Token` encrypted on your device, avoid saving the user name and Password.

Comment: What is that? Any example???

Comment: When the user logins for the first time with credentials (login and password), you just need to encrypt and encode and send the credentials to your server, further the server will provide you with a unique `Access token` to make future accessible queries on the server, this `Access token` which is used in all future queries on the server is required to be saved in your local system (in ecrypted form)

Comment: Example would be using the `Facebook SDK` to access Facebook features.

Comment: Need to have offline authorization!! That we are using already for online access

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is not to save them at all.  Encrypting provides very little security in this case because the app itself has to have the decryption key, so the key and data are on the same device.  It will prevent only the least determined attackers.  An OS level device isn't much better, as anyone with physical access can easily get around it.

The best idea is to use an access token.  Get the login data once, send it to the server to login, and have them respond with an id.  Use that id in future requests to identify yourself.  The server should remember who is associated with each id.  Preferably the server will include a timeout mechanism, where after X amount of time the id will be invalidated and the user will need to log in again.  Even more secure implementations will match it to some physical id of the device as well, such as the Android device id, requiring attackers to have the device or fake both pieces of information.

The use of an access token rather than saving credentials protects the users in a few ways.  First, the attacker will not know the users password in case its reused for other services (like their email).  Second, it will not be enough to change their password (because a secure service will ask for the password again to change it) so while the info in the account may be compromised the user can take back the account by using their password to change their password.  If the actual password is saved and lost the attacker can change the login info and lock the user out of his account permanently.

Comment: Is there a way to store like in keychain for iOS?